# Android edit text cursor is not visible?

Tags: android, android-edittext

```
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:shape="rectangle">
 <solid android:color="#ffffff" />    
 <stroke android:width="1dp" 
  android:color="#000000" />
 </shape>
```

I am using this code in `setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selfbg);`
While I am using this code the cursor is not visible in Edittext.

Answer (score 47):

Did you try?

Setting the `android:textCursorDrawable` attribute to @null should result in the use of `android:textColor` as the cursor color.

Answer (score 11):

try to add below into EditText:

```
 android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
 android:background="@null"
```

Answer (score 7):

```
<EditText  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor"
    android:background="@drawable/R.drawable.selfbg"/>


Than create drawalble xml: color_cursor

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <size android:width="2dp" />
    <solid android:color="#000000"  />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 6):

try:

```
 <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@null</item>
```

It requires API-12 and above though.

Answer (score 1):

try this

In your EditText, use the property:

```
android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/black_cursor"
```

and add the drawable black_cursor.xml to your resources, as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <size android:width="0dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1):

**MainActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText.requestFocus();
    editText.setSelection(0);
}
```

**activity_main**

```
 <LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            layout="@layout/content_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

**content_main**

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

As you can see, my EditText is not in activity_main, but in content_main, which I included in activity_main anyway hoping it would work the same, but NO... It doesn't work like that unfortunately. So I change my activity_main like this and it works like a charm.

```
**activity_main**

 <LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think that you cant "setTextCursorDrawable" by code .

ive looked into the Android documentation of [EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) and [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) and there is no such method .

so you have to do it in the xml layout .

Answer (score 0):

If you want this done through java code only 
try this

In TextView class you can find the code below

```
case com.android.internal.R.styleable.TextView_textCursorDrawable:
    mCursorDrawableRes = a.getResourceId(attr, 0);
    break;
```

but the method textCursorDrawable() is only existed in R.attr, if you wanna set this attribute, you can only call the construct method below by including a editText in XML file.

```
public EditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, com.android.internal.R.attr.editTextStyle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must include requestFocus in EditText in the xml, that way it works, on the contrary I see many examples without i tested them they are not working, just works when I add requestFocus.